# App Engine and Eclipse on Ubuntu Linux 12.10

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, ubuntu

I updated Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10.

It upgraded my Eclipse too, from 3.7 to 3.8.

Turns out, Google App Engine doesn't have a plug in for 3.8. Just 3.7 and 4.2.

So I upgraded Eclipse to 4.2.

When I upload my project, it says it can't because of the java-7 flags. I found a post on here that described how I might change the flag, but it wouldn't matter because I'm not a "Trusted Tester" so they wouldn't allow it yet anyways.

I tried to change the Project's build path to include OpenJDK 6 and a compiler level of 1.6

I get this project error "Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet."

I've looked it up, and found a message on StackOverflow, but I can't figure out what facets I'm using or if that solution even applies.

Is it possible to use Eclipse 4.2 and the App Engine 1.7.4 to upload a project to App Engine?

How do I get it to use Java6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it possible to use Eclipse 4.2 and the App Engine 1.7.4 to upload a project to App Engine?**

Yes it is, that's what I use. Have you tried creating a new project after you set the jdk to 6? I had this exact same issue at first, and creating a new project was all it took once I got the jdk right.

Comment: I added openJDK6 to the JREs and set that default. When I create a new project, I can see java-6-openjdk as the projects JRE. When I run it locally, I get "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0". The compiler was still set to 1.7 for the project. So I changed it to 1.6. Now the project won't even run because I get the original "Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet." Dead in the water. Trying to avoid having to uninstall and reinstall everything... but might not be able to

Comment: It's a type "Faceted Project Problem". One of the answers on stackoverflow says right click the project and bring up properties, then look at "Facets" but I don't see that in my version of Eclipse. (I since redownloaded 3.7 to see if I can get back to work, but no luck)

Comment: I see. Try this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694648/gae-getting-started-in-java-eclipse-indigo-cant-compile-as-1-6

Comment: So I set the default compile as well as the JDK to 1.6, deleted, recreated the project, and it looks like its working. I haven't uploaded to App Engine yet, but it's not java7 so it should work fine. Thanks!