# Java 7 support for Google App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, thread-dump

The Google App Engine Java [overview page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview) indicates that the Java versions 5 and 6 are supported. When starting the local development server with Java 7u4 the following error bubbles up:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0x000000010d733a96, pid=32766, tid=140735250205024
#
# JRE version: 7.0_04-b21
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J  com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitInsn(I)V
#
```

For more information please refer to the [output](http://pastebin.com/rP1WAunw) and the [thread dump](http://pastebin.com/r72ff0gC).

Is there any known issue with this particular Java 7 version? Is there going to be full Java 7 support for GAE Java on the roadmap?

Comment: Java 7 is simply not supported. What more do you expect? Are you _surprised_ that there are problems using an unsupported version?

Comment: I am not surprised. However, I know that some people did use JRE 7 in a different minor version and GAE worked fine for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Is there any known issue with this particular Java 7 version?`

We're well aware of Java 1.7 issues.

`Is there going to be full Java 7 support for GAE Java on the roadmap?`

Until we've made some official announcement, we have to ask for patience.

Answer (score 3):

As of AppEngine 1.7.7, support has been added for Java 7.

http://googleappengine.blogspot.ca/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any known issue with this particular Java 7 version?

Well, as you stated it's not supported.

Also, this 2011 [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/IEAohfEN-oE) seems to reference a similar bug on OS X and announces a bugfix.

> Is there going to be full Java 7 support for GAE Java on the roadmap?

Probably not for a rather long while.

You could, however, try to force the use of a 1.6 source format and a 1.6 target class format, in your Eclipse project (or whichever build system you use).

### Further Reading:

- [Is it possible to use Java 7 on GAE?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/IEAohfEN-oE) *(from the [google-appengine-java](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java) mailing-list)*
- [Google App Engine and Java Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139477/google-app-engine-and-java-version)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what has been announced [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes)  on this recently:

> Version 1.7.3 - October 23, 2012
>
> We encourage you to try and test your application using Java 7 and the
> App Engine SDK. Note that Java 7 is not a supported runtime.
>
> **Java 7
> Features that we encourage you to try in dev appserver:**
>
> Strings in switch
>
> Binary integral literals and underscores in number literals
>
> Multi-catch and more precise rethrow
>
> Improved type inference for
> generic instance creation (diamond)
>
> try-with-resources statement
>
> Simplified varargs method invocation

---

> **Java 7 features that are NOT supported:**
>
> All new Java 7 classes (the Google App Engine whitelist has
> not been updated yet)
>
> Method Handles
>
> Invoke Dynamic bytecode