# Google Cloud - App Engine - Java - SDK install

Tags: java, windows, google-app-engine

**Google Cloud - App Engine - Java - SDK install:**

Part of the sdk install instructions are as follows:

> Install the SDK on Windows:
>
> Double click the appengine-java-sdk-1.9.49.zip file that you
>   downloaded to extract the SDK to a directory of your choice.
>
> The App Engine Java SDK requires Java 7 bytecode level. You can use
>   either Java 7 or Java 8; be sure to set the javac compiler flags to
>   generate 1.7 bytecode:
>
> ```
>  -source 1.7 -target 1.7
> ```
>
> If you don't have Java or the correct Java version installed, download
>   and install the Java SE Development Kit (JDK) for Windows.

So I have Java 8 installed. How do i configure the SDK to use the javac compiler flags to generate  1.7 bytecode? Please don't answer adding the options -source 1.7 - target 1.7 to my javac command line as the SDK doesn't have me individually compiling things using the command line! Im expecting to find a config file someplace that has an element i can configure for compiling done by the SDK --- Confused thanks !

Comment: What do you means by 'as the SDK doesn't have me individually compiling things using the command line!' ?

Comment: My java version is currently 1.8. The App Engine SDK itself compiles things, i dont see a config file where i can effect the compile options to create 1.7 bytecode as i dont run  javac - the SDK does automatically! Seems like i should be able to control this better than setting a java_home to a 1.7 java installation in the cmd shell where i start the App Engine SDK

Comment: Is that answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139477/google-app-engine-and-java-version